# Newest version of Openscad not correctly installing for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, cad

I followed the directions listed [here](http://www.openscad.org/downloads.html#linux) to install Openscad.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openscad/releases 
$ sudo apt-get install openscad
```

When I check the version it says that I am running 2014.01.29 instead of 2015-03.1. I am looking for search() module support. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To get the latest version I had to use [the following code](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Building_on_Linux/UNIX):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chrysn/openscad
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openscad
```